# Decode/Analyse the following UART signals

Tags: uart, communication

I have sent a 2 and a 9 using UART. The baud rate is 9600, there is no parity, and it has 8 data bits.

As we know 9 is represented as 1001 in binary. However, this is what I get from my UART signal:

[image]

A 2 is represented as 0010 but this is what I get from my UART signal:
[image]
I know I have to pay attention to the start bit, but other than that, I have a hard time seing the logic in this signal.

**NOTE:**

The signal works, but I just need help analysing it.

Comment: Without even looking at the waveform, you may be confusing binary numbers and ASCII character codes, eg, the numeric value 2 vs the character '2' which has the ascii code 0x32.  Also please don't use random tags, tags are for what a question is *about* now what was tangentially involved but plays no part in your post.

Comment: Your scope looks modern enough to have UART decoding, although perhaps it's also new enough that you have to pay for the privilege.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let's annotate your first scope shot. When we do this take note that the lowest order bit of the binary value is transmitted first. Conventional notation in this field is to order the bits in a byte like this:

[Bit 7][Bit 6][Bit 5][Bit 4][Bit 3][Bit 2][Bit 1][Bit 0]

So when I annotate and then evaluate the bit positions are flipped from the positions shown on the annotated scope shots.

[image]

The bit pattern represented there is 0b00111001.

That is the same as 0x39.

0x39 is the ASCII code for a '9' character.

Let's do the same for your second scope shot.

[image]

Here the bit pattern is represented as 0b00110010.

That is same as 0x32.

0x32 is the ASCII code for the '2' character.

Comment: The ASCII explanation sort of makes sense but I don't get why bit 0 is skipped.

Comment: For the character 9 you only write 0b00111001, but if we include bit 0 it would be 0b100111001

Comment: Start bits are always a zero level bit and are the same width. Your second pictures red lines are actually marking bit 1. Bit 0 is not skipped.

Comment: Stop bits are always a one level bit and are the same width. The stop bit is not part of the UART 8-bits data.

Comment: Are you saying that bit 0 is the start bit?

Comment: No. The start bit is clearly marked in my annotations and is not Bit 0.

Comment: But why don't we include it in the bit pattern you wrote down then?

Comment: Especially if bit 0 is a '1' like in the first picture.

Comment: I wrote the bit patterns for just the 8-bit data portion of the UART transmission. I did not include the start and stop bits.

Comment: Then how do you get a '1' in the end of 0b00111001 when the last bit in the picture before the stop bit is a '0'? I'm talking about the first picture in this case.

Comment: I'm saying that the bit patterns you write down, don't look like the bit patterns I see in the pictures.

Comment: You are reading them backwards.  LSB means least significant bit comes first.  You need to invert them left to right.

Comment: I denoted the bit numbers in the pictures. In this discipline bit 0 is the least significant bit.

Answer (score 11):

You probably sent an ASCII 9, not a binary 9. ASCII 9 is 0x39. Bits are sent LSbit first.

0011 1001 reversed is 1001 1100

[image]

Answer (score 9):

UARTs usually send the least-significant bit first hence you get this for 9 and lower down for 2: -

[image]

UART character frame: -

[image]

Comment: Oh misery, a downvote - anyone feel man-enough to own up to this?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but your answer is the only one that doesn’t mention ASCII.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, those are not numbers 9 and 2, but ASCII character symbols '9' and '2', which equal to 0x39 and 0x32.

The bits are also sent LSB first. That's why you see a leading 0 start bit, and then 10011100 for '9' and 01001100 for '2'.

Answer (score 5):

The `2` that you sent is actually the *character* two, not the decimal value of 2. The ASCII code for 2 is 0x32 or 0b00110010, which matches one of your images. Also, the bits are sent from LSB to MSB, so the levels you see on the 'scope would be 0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0 from left to right.